# REST API Keep Alive

Tags: api, rest

The first time the rest api, is hit it takes between 15 to 20 seconds to get a reply. Is there any way to keep the api alive, because if I hit it a second time it takes between 2 - 4 seconds.This is the same behavior when I use workbench